# Can root test whether a monitor is connected?

Tags: monitors

I use a script in `/etc/acpi` to turn off the screen (`xset dpms force
off`) when I close my laptop's lid.  Now I want it to act differently
when an external monitor is connected (set brightness to zero
instead).  I know I can test whether it is connected with `xrandr`,
but the script is run by root, and xrandr depends on a certain
X-session.  Is there a way for root to test whether the monitor is
connected, regardless of X-sessions?  I'm using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Method #1 - edid-decode

You can use `edid-decode` to see what monitors are connected. This is from an Ubuntu 16.04 system I have, but this worked in Fedora 28 & CentOS 7.x as well.

**NOTE:** This particular system has two video ports, I'm using the VGA one.

Here the monitor is plugged in:

```
$ ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -n 1 edid-decode | grep Manufacturer:
Manufacturer: DEL Model a071 Serial Number 844247885
Manufacturer: @@@ Model 0 Serial Number 0
```

And here is when I unplug the VGA monitor:

```
$ ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -n 1 edid-decode | grep Manufacturer:
Manufacturer: @@@ Model 0 Serial Number 0
Manufacturer: @@@ Model 0 Serial Number 0
```

And here it is plugged back in:

```
$ ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -n 1 edid-decode | grep Manufacturer:
Manufacturer: DEL Model a071 Serial Number 844247885
Manufacturer: @@@ Model 0 Serial Number 0
```

#### Method #2 - cat sysfs

If you poke around under `/sys` the display ports that you have are listed here under `/sys/class/drm`.

```
$ ls /sys/class/drm
card0  card0-DP-1  card0-HDMI-A-1  controlD64  renderD128  version
```

The display ports for monitors will be `card0-DP-1` (VGA) and the `card0-HDMI-A-1` (HDMI). If you look in each of these directories, there's a file called `status`. If you `cat` this file you can see the port's status and whether a monitor is connected or not.

Same test as above, plugged in:

```
$ cat /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/status
connected
```

Unplugged:

```
$ cat /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/status
disconnected
```

#### References

- [How to create a callback for “monitor plugged” on an intel graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469828/how-to-create-a-callback-for-monitor-plugged-on-an-intel-graphics)
- [How do I find out monitor make / model?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98226/how-do-i-find-out-monitor-make-model)

Comment: When you power off the external monitor it still shows as "connected" by both `xrandr` and `/sys/class/drm/*/status`. I'm looking to find out instantly as soon as the monitor is turned off, not unplugged. Any suggestions?